# bubble chart: how to change names and range of a tile, and the layout of the plot

Tags: r, layout, ggplot2, tiles

I would like to make changes to my bubble plot’s layout and tile. Unfortunately, I could not figure out how to change  my code below to have the desired format.

```
ggplot(test, aes(y = modules, x = correlation, colour=direction, size = pvalue)) + 
  geom_point(data = subset(test, correlation > 0.5 & pvalue > 1.3)) + 
  facet_grid(facets = . ~ Label)  + ggtitle("Module-Trait Association")  + 
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 10, color = "black")) +  
  theme(strip.background = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = "white",size = 1, linetype = NULL))  + scale_size_continuous(range = c(0, 12))+ 
  scale_colour_manual(values=c(down= "blue", up = "red")) + theme_bw() + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
    strip.background = element_rect(colour="white", fill="white"), 
    panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black")
  )
```

1. The correlation values are between 0.5 and 1, so the grid values on the x axis range from 0.5 to 0.9. The edge of many bubbles (r=0.75 or higher) are off the chart even when I decreased the size.  I would like to change x-axis to  the range of  0.3 – 1.2.
2. I would like  to change the names of tile which are right now the names of the columns “direction” (to "EigenGene Direction") and “pvalue” (to “log10(p)”).
3. Most importantly, I would like to change the range of  bubble size  representing p-values in the tile. It displays 5 bubbles ranging from 2 to 4  (2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4).  I would like to have bubbles with size ranging from 1 to 4.

Would you please advise?

Thank you in advance.
Anita

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my question in case if you have similar issues.

```
ggplot(test, aes(y = modules,x = correlation, colour=direction, size = pvalue))+ 
  geom_point(data = subset(test, correlation > 0.5 & pvalue > 1.3))+
  facet_grid(facets = . ~ Label,margins = FALSE)+ 
  ggtitle("Module -Trait Association")+
  labs(x="Correlation", y="Module")+
  theme(strip.background = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = "white",size = 10, linetype = NULL))+
  scale_colour_manual("EigenGene Direction", values=c(down= "blue", up = "red")) +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),strip.background = element_rect(colour="white", fill="white"),panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black",size = 1.2))+
  scale_size_area("p-value",max_size = 75, limits= c(1,50), breaks= c(1.3, 2, 3,4),labels= c("0.05","0.01","0.001","0.0001")) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0.5,0.7,0.9,1.1), limits=c(0.4,1.2), labels = c("0.5", "0.7","0.9", "1.1")) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=6))) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size=12,colour = "black"),strip.text.x = element_text(colour = "black", face= "bold",angle = 0, size = 12)) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 12,angle = 90,vjust = 1, face="bold"), axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12,angle = 0,vjust = 1, face="bold")) +
  theme(legend.position= "right",legend.text = element_text(colour="black", size=10, face="bold"), legend.title = element_text(colour="black", size=12,face="bold"), plot.title=element_text(size=25))
```